# Prolog: Obtain 1st element in "list of lists"

Tags: prolog

I have a "list of lists" e.g. [[A,B,C],[A,B],[D,F]].

I now wish to print to the screen the first element of the list, (i.e. [A,B,C] in this example). I had thought I could do this as follows:

```
testfunction(List):-
    List=[[Top]|Rest],
    write(Top),nl,nl.
```

However, when I run this with `testfunction([[A,B,C],[A,B],[D,F]]).` it seems to fail at the `List=[[Top]|Rest]` unification step.

I have been racking my brains for ages, but I can't work out why it is failing - can somebody see where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: My advice: Do not start with printing things. Instead use the [tag:prolog-toplevel].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the vertical bar `[Top|Rest]` syntax twice in order to pull out an element from the nested list, like this:

```
testfunction([[Top|_]|_]):-
    write(Top),nl,nl.
```

Now `Top` unifies with the first element of the first list in a list of lists. Note that you do not have to use unification operator `=` at all, and do the unification inside the header.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/votAz9)

Comment: aaaa yes I understand, many thanks for your help. Just one follow-up question: when I now print out Top it prints something like "_G2134", whereas I want to actually print the value it is bound to. How do I do this?

Comment: A wait never mind - I think it was just that I needed to put quotation marks around the A, B, etc. so they are seen as text as opposed to variables.